# unique_ptr/auto_ptr look alike with custom deleter for c++98

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, raii, auto-ptr

auto_ptr doesn't support custom deleter and tr1 `shared_ptr` is not a good option for me.
Are there any good options before c11 for `unique_ptr`/ `auto_ptr` look alike with custom deleter?

Comment: Use the boost library implementations?

Comment: my boost version is 1.33.1. I boost/scoped_ptr doesn't have a deleter and I can't seem to compile with <boost/interprocess/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp>. boost unique_ptr is from version 1.57

Comment: By `c11` do you mean `C++11`?

Comment: @PeretzLevinov is there anything hindering you from updating to Boost 1.57 (or later)?

Comment: Why are you using a pre C++11 compiler. Is it due to a limitation of the OS platform your are using or is it a project limitation? BTW you should never use auto_ptr which is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

### Boost.Move: unique_ptr (C++03, Boost 1.57)

A `unique_ptr` implementation without the move semantics of C++11 (and beyond) is a bit tricky, but if you could emulate move semantics, you could go forward with an implementation of similar semantics as that of [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Boost provided this very implementation for C++03, as part of the Boost.Move library:

> #### What is Boost.Move?
>
> Rvalue references are a major C++0x feature, enabling move semantics
>   for C++ values. However, we don't need C++0x compilers to take
>   advantage of move semanatics. Boost.Move emulates C++0x move semantics
>   in C++03 compilers and allows writing portable code that works
>   optimally in C++03 and C++0x compilers.

Specifically, [from Boost 1.57 and onwards](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/move-unique-ptr-c-14-unique-ptr-comes-to-town-td4666785.html), providing [`boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp)

> ```
> //!\file
> //! Describes the smart pointer unique_ptr, a drop-in replacement for std::unique_ptr,
> //! usable also from C++03 compilers.
> //!
> //! Main differences from std::unique_ptr to avoid heavy dependencies,
> //! specially in C++03 compilers:
> //!   - <tt>operator < </tt> uses pointer <tt>operator < </tt>instead of <tt>std::less<common_type></tt>. 
> //!      This avoids dependencies on <tt>std::common_type</tt> and <tt>std::less</tt>
> //!      (<tt><type_traits>/<functional></tt> headers. In C++03 this avoid pulling Boost.Typeof and other
> //!      cascading dependencies. As in all Boost platforms <tt>operator <</tt> on raw pointers and
> //!      other smart pointers provides strict weak ordering in practice this should not be a problem for users.
> //!   - assignable from literal 0 for compilers without nullptr
> //!   - <tt>unique_ptr<T[]></tt> is constructible and assignable from <tt>unique_ptr<U[]></tt> if
> //!      cv-less T and cv-less U are the same type and T is more CV qualified than U.
> ```

which allows providing an associated non-default deleter to the `unique_ptr`:

> ```
> //! A unique pointer is an object that owns another object and
> //! manages that other object through a pointer.
> //! 
> //! ...
> //!
> //! \tparam T Provides the type of the stored pointer.
> //! \tparam D The deleter type:
> //!   -  The default type for the template parameter D is default_delete. A client-supplied template argument
> //!      D shall be a function object type, lvalue-reference to function, or lvalue-reference to function object type
> //!      for which, given a value d of type D and a value ptr of type unique_ptr<T, D>::pointer, the expression
> //!      d(ptr) is valid and has the effect of disposing of the pointer as appropriate for that deleter.
> //!   -  If the deleter's type D is not a reference type, D shall satisfy the requirements of Destructible.
> //!   -  If the type <tt>remove_reference<D>::type::pointer</tt> exists, it shall satisfy the requirements of NullablePointer.
> template <class T, class D = default_delete<T> >
> class unique_ptr
> {
>     /* ... */
> }
> ```